# Network MSSQL with local failover

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, windows-7, database, sql

I currently have a database setup where my MSSQL 2008 R2 server runs on my local network, but the program runs on a notebook that is normally mobile and away from the network. VPN works, but I'm looking for a solution that that runs a local MSSQl 2008 R2 server on the local machine that syncs with the main server when the mobile system reconnects to the network, either through VPN or coming back on the network.

The notebook is running Windows 7 Professional 64 bit, the server Server 2008 Enterprise 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Give MS-SQL server permanent merge replication a try. It is a lot of work to setup the whole thing, but if you succeed it runs like a charm, when ever a network-connection is established.

This way you will be able to insert/update/delete data on either side, your notebook or your server on your local network. as soon a network connection is established the data will be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Out of box Merge Replication is suitable for this.. But if you want your own implementation try Sync framework.